# App appears to hang in instruments (Energy consumption) when navigate to UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I build a native iOS app and my app also having UIWebview to load html page,but problem arises when trying to profile their iOS app for energy consumption using the Xcode instruments tool. and when navigate to the app from UIVewController to UIWebView , the app appears to hang.

Code for Navigation :

```
if ((weakSelf.presentedViewController) && [weakSelf.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            if ([((UINavigationController *)weakSelf.presentedViewController).topViewController isKindOfClass:[TestViewController class]]){
                [[Logger sharedInstance] logInfo:@"I am already in Hybrid Page"];

                return ;
            }
        }
        TestViewController *hybridViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *hybridNavViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hybridViewController];
        [weakSelf.navigationController presentViewController:hybridNavViewController
                                                    animated:YES
                                                  completion:nil];
        [TestbstractController setNavigationController:hybridNavViewController];
```

Comment: can you post a code with your question for navigate

Comment: update my question with code